# Getting percentage value of records using the max count of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm a newbie to SQL learner and I have an issue I'd like you all to help me with. I've got a table `User_Activity_Log` that contains the names of students with their ID (`user_id`), Date of Attendance in the year (`User_timestamp`) in the format (February 25,2015).

Say the `User_Activity_Log` table contains

```
| user_id | user_timestamp | 
| jude    | February 22    |
| jude    | February 24    |
| annie   | February 1     |
| sam     | January        |
```

I'd like to know how to get a table showing the User Id, the number of counts a student is seen in the month and the percentage count, which should be gotten from the max(count) of a student.

Here's what I've done so far, this gives me error.

```
USE FinalYearProject
declare @maxval int

select 
    @maxval = (SELECT MAX(fromsubq.SM) as PA
               FROM
                    (SELECT COUNT (user_Id) as SM
                     FROM dbo.User_Activity_Log
                     WHERE user_Timestamp LIKE 'February%'
                     GROPU BY User_Id) fromsubq
              ) 

(SELECT COUNT 
 FROM dbo.User_Activity_Log
 WHERE user_Timestamp like 'February%'
 GROUP BY user_Id) * 100.0 / @maxval
```

Expected output should be

```
| User_id | Count | PercentageCount |
| Jude    |   2   |      100 %      |
| annie   |   1   |       50  %     |
| sam     |   0   |        0   %    |
```

Please help me point out the problem and possible solutions

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `user_timestamp` a `varchar`?

Comment: Yes sir it is a varchar

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If it's SQL Server, what version?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: here i've added it sir

Comment: |User_id|Count|PercentageCount|
|Jude |     2|       100 %|
|annie|     1|        50  %|
|sam  |      0|        0   %|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using conditional aggregation in a subquery/cte and adding `OVER()` to an aggregate:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT User_ID
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN user_timestamp LIKE 'February%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CT
              FROM User_Activity_Log
              GROUP BY User_ID
              )
SELECT User_ID
      ,CT
      ,CT*100.0 / MAX(CT) OVER() AS PercentageCount
FROM cte
ORDER BY CT DESC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef18f/7/0)

Note: It's bad practice to store dates as strings, if you can avoid it at all you should.

Edit: Here's how it would be done with a subquery instead of `cte`:

```
SELECT User_ID
      ,CT
      ,CT*100.0 / MAX(CT) OVER() AS PercentageCount
FROM (SELECT User_ID
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN user_timestamp LIKE 'February%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CT
      FROM User_Activity_Log
      GROUP BY User_ID
      ) AS Sub
ORDER BY CT DESC
```

UPDATE:  To use the `PercentageCount` in a `CASE` expression, something like:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT User_ID
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN user_timestamp LIKE 'February%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CT
              FROM User_Activity_Log
              GROUP BY User_ID
              )
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT User_ID
                      ,CT
                     ,CT*100.0 / MAX(CT) OVER() AS PercentageCount                  
               FROM cte
               )
SELECT *,CASE WHEN PercentageCount > .5 THEN 'Qualified' ELSE 'NotQualified' END AS Qualified
FROM cte2
ORDER BY CT DESC
```

Comment: @Emma `common table expressions` (I often alias mine as `cte` are much like subqueries, they have some added benefits such as recursion, but in situations like this, I just think it looks cleaner than a subquery.

Comment: how would it have been done.. if i were to use sub queries @Hart CO

Comment: thanks for your answer it has really been helpful... However id like to compute the percentage value such that it displays the table displays another column if percentage count is greater than say 50percent.. The column should write qualified.. Thanks for your response

Comment: @Emma Not sure I follow, instead of returning the Percentage you want to evaluate it and return a string based on some criteria?  If so, you can put the percentage calculation in a `CASE` expression, like: `CASE WHEN **insert calculation** > .5 THEN 'Qualified' ELSE 'NotQualified' END`

Comment: yes id like to add a column that gives either qualified if d percentagecount is greater than 50percent.. Like this. But i dont know where to put the case expression in the previous query.

Comment: Cool... So is there a way to use the alias (percentage count) rather than writing out the calculated expression

Comment: @Emma If you wrapped that query inside of another cte/subquery you could use the alias.

Comment: Ok.. @hart CO,  pardon me for pushing you further.. How would i do that using another cte/subquery.Thanks alot.. Hope to sharing a coffee with you someday..

Comment: Ok.. @hart CO,  pardon me for pushing you further.. How would i do that using another cte/subquery.Thanks alot.. Hope to sharing a coffee with you someday..

Answer (score 0):

First find the `Count` per `user_id` in `sub-select` then find the the percentage in outer query.

Use `max over()` to find the max value in `count` then divide each count by max count to get the percentage. Try this.

```
SELECT user_Id,
       Cnt                      AS [Count],
       ( Cnt / Max(Cnt) OVER() ) * 100 AS PercentageCount
FROM   (SELECT Count(user_Id) AS Cnt,
               user_Id,
        FROM   dbo.User_Activity_Log
        WHERE  user_Timestamp LIKE 'February%'
        GROUP  BY User_Id) A
```

Comment: When i ran this I had  |User_id|Count|PercentageCount|
                                    |Jude   |2    |100 %          |
                                    |annie  |1    |0  %             |                                  Not all the user id column names show and the percentage count for annie should be 50 not 0 Pls help clarify